# Is there a term for a person who takes everything like it’s written in stone?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if you say you’ll be there at 10, you better show up at exactly 10, not 10:04. My son is like this. If we make a rule, we cannot change it without a fight.

Comment: I'll go with *adamant*: refusing to be persuaded or to change one's mind.

Comment: The duplicate target doesn't seem right. A person who takes something literally, (e.g. upon hearing "throw the baby out with the bathwater", expects there to be a baby involved), is not the same thing as someone who understands what is being said, and wants to adhere to that strictly.

Answer (score 4):

I would describe such a person as [fastidious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fastidious)

> giving too much attention to small details and wanting everything to be correct and perfect

Comment: or maybe 'inflexible'

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, that would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

**unyielding**

> (of a person or their behavior) unlikely to be swayed; resolute.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unyielding)

> You describe someone as unyielding when they have very strong, fixed
> ideas about something and are unlikely to change their mind.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unyielding)

---

> Miss Kuhlman said that initially waiting for their turn was rather
> chaotic, but after the first couple of weeks, they understood that
> waiting politely for their turn was the only way they would be able to
> ride the tricycle. Miss Kuhlman was **unyielding** about her rules. [B. E.
> Lithander; *Life's Pages—A Story Worth Sharing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_s_Pages/IF1XAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Miss%20Kuhlman%20said%20that%20initially%20waiting%20for%20their%20turn%20was%20rather%20chaotic&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> He thought as a judge down to the time when he had made up his mind,
> and after that his obstinacy was **unyielding**. [*The American Law
> Review*, Vol. 25](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_American_Law_Review/rgBCAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20unyielding%20his%20opinion&pg=PA444&printsec=frontcover) p.25 (1891)